# How to use the `exec_insert` method?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I am running the following raw SQL:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO articles (`title`, `user_id`) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

However, I would like to use the Ruby on Rails [`exec_insert`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_insert) method but there isn't good documentation about that. So, how can I use the `exec_insert` method so to make the same thing I stated above (maybe using something like `Article.connection.exec_insert(...)`)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`exec_insert` is an internal method and probably isn't what you want here. What you have should be fine.

If you're really set on using it, and need examples, the test suite possibly the best place to find them. One example is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/adapters/sqlite3/sqlite3_adapter_test.rb#L43).

Comment: According to documentation, `execute` is discouraged and dangerous, and `exec_insert` might be better fit: _"Executes the SQL statement in the context of this connection and returns the raw result from the connection adapter. Note: depending on your database connector, the result returned by this method may be manually memory managed. Consider using the #exec_query wrapper instead."_

Comment: Sorry, it's not a private method. You can check its documentation here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_insert

Answer (score 4):

You can use `exec_query` for this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection().exec_query('INSERT INTO articles(title, user_id) VALUES($1, $2)', 'someQueryName', [[nil, title], [nil, user_id]])
```

**Please note** that I have used and tested $1, $2 **for Postgres only** as $1,$2  is the convention used for binding prepare query in postgres.

*It maybe different for MySql & other databases. For Mysql I think it should be `?` instead of $1, $2 etc*, it depends on how the database offers binding

Also you might have to set `prepare_query: true` for some. Refer -http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#exec_query